# Control Caption Text is displayed smaller

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a Userform in Excel that has to be dynamically generated each time. It can list many (100+) lines which are all exactly the same in format. These are generated by the following code snippet.

```
' ctextbox
Set ctl = .Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
With ctl
    .Top = 12 + linetop
    .Left = 464.9
    .Width = 140
    .Height = 18
    .Name = FieldName & "_ctextbox"
End With
' cshow
Set ctl = .Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With ctl
    .Top = 13.1 + linetop
    .Left = 611.35
    .Width = 41.95
    .Height = 18
    .Name = FieldName & "_cshow"
    .Caption = "Show All"
End With
' confirm
Set ctl = .Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1")
With ctl
    .Top = 13.5 + linetop
    .Left = 659
    .Width = 44.95
    .Height = 17.25
    .Name = FieldName & "_confirm"
    .Caption = "Confirm"
End With
```

It would fine except for a random occurrence where the Confirm checkbox appears smaller than the rest. The screenshot below shows what I mean.

[image: Screenshot of form]

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: Try using `Me.Repaint` after the controls have been generated.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what was required.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Would you mind posting your answer as an answer? This way I can then close this question. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you want me to post the answer? You can choose your own answer as well. ;)

Comment: You answered it, so I prefer to give credit where credit is due. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `repainting` the Userform after you have added the controls dynamically.

The Repaint method completes any pending screen updates for a specified form. When performed on a form, the Repaint method also completes any pending recalculations of the form's controls.

This method is useful if the contents or appearance of an object changes and you don't want to wait until the system automatically repaints the area. `Me.Repaint` simply updates the display by redrawing the form

Comment: For some reason this isn't working all of the time. I'll keep persisting though. Maybe I need to call it in a few different places.

Comment: I would love to see your file if that is a possibility :)

Comment: Unfortunately the NDA stops me from providing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in that my repaint did not work. I solved this by setting the CheckBox AutoSize property to True and I have no problems anymore.